# Sort facets of an Altair plot bases on group statistic

Tags: python, sorting, facet, altair

I would like to change the order of the facets of an Altair chart based based on some groups statistics such as mean,  sigma,  etc.

In some cases,  the ordering function may be more complex,  such as the delta between two moving averages,  slope of an EWMA,  etc,   so I would also like to be able to "pass" in the order if possible.

Here's the testable case code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import altair as alt

alt.renderers.enable('notebook')

# make some data to test
N = 500
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date Time': pd.date_range('2019-06-19', periods=N, freq='H'),
    'A':  np.random.normal(6, 1, N),
    'B': np.random.normal(5, 1, N),
    'C': np.random.normal(7, 1, N),
    'D': np.random.normal(8, 1, N)
}).melt('Date Time')

# render the chart using facets
p = alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    facet='variable',
    y='value',
    x='Date Time',
    color='variable',
)

# set some aditional properties
p.properties(width=230, height=150, columns=3).resolve_scale()
```

Which produces this chart where the facets are sorted alphabetically:

[image]

I would like the sort order to be largest mean to smallest mean:

```
var_order = df.groupby('variable').mean().sort_values('variable', ascending=False).index.values
var_order
```

which produces:

```
array(['D', 'C', 'B', 'A'], dtype=object)
```

I read some posts that indicate sorting on x and y is possible,  but this is case where I would like to sort the faces themselves.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an `EncodingSortField` on the `facet` encoding; e.g.

```
p = alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    y='value',
    x='Date Time',
    color='variable',
    facet=alt.Facet('variable',
        sort=alt.EncodingSortField('value', op='mean', order='descending')
    )
)

# set some aditional properties
p.properties(width=230, height=150, columns=3).resolve_scale()
```

[image: chart output]

For more complicated calculations, you can use a calculate transform and/or aggregate transform to compute a new field, and sort by that.

Comment: Well,  that was fast :).    I post,  walk down to the cafe for lunch,  then you have the answer already posted.  FYI - Nice work overall on Altair.  It's the closet to R Grid/Lattice I have found so far,  and has a more straightforward,  easy to use  interface vs. Bokeh (IMHO).  Keep up the awesome work... and if/when I can,  maybe I'll answer an Altair related question on Stack Overflow.